# Magit select modules in status window

Tags: magit

How do I select multiple modules in the magit status window so I can update them all at once? What is the magic key binding that tags/marks them for that operation (o u)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered best [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38996) with references to the relevant manual bits. Basically, use Emacs regions for selection, or use the universal prefix `C-u` before issuing the command, to apply to all modules (e.g., update becomes `o C-u u`).